# How are eBooks cited for a paper due to be published by a university in the U.S.?

Tags: citations

I've literally found 4 different styles so far, and counting.

The American Mathematical Society, or at least a website that claims to have association with it, says to use APA, meanwhile literally every single math paper I've ever seen in my life, including by graduates in the U.S., does not use APA at all, it uses a discrete bibliographic system that labels references with square brackets and always places the publication year later, references the volume and uses square brackets for in-text citations as well, comparable to wikipedia.

Which one is right? The American Mathematical Society or thousands of published mathematicians? I can't understand how the fields centered most around consensus somehow have the least consensus.

Comment: Where does the AMS say to use APA style?  Link, please.  Books and journals published by the AMS don't use anything of the kind.  But generally, there is not necessarily any standard; each journal/publisher selects its own preferred style.  There is no "right" approach.

Comment: Nowhere did I reference anything published "by" the AMS, I don't know why you suggest that when I stated a university as the publisher in the question title.

Comment: "The American Mathematical Society, or at least a website that claims to have association with it, says to use APA".  Could you please give a link to who exactly says this, and where?  My point is that I don't understand why they would say this, when their own journals don't use it.

Comment: There are two things I don't understand about your question. The headline mentions eBooks, but the text does not. Are you interested in eBooks at all? Second, I don't know what you mean by "published by" a university. Do you mean just published (in a journal or conference) and authored by those associated with the university or do you mean specifically _University publications_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no universal standard for "papers published by a university in the US".  Many different styles exist, and different journals may prefer different styles.  This may be the case even for different journals published by the same university press.  You'll have to check each journal for the style they want.  It will often be on their website, under "instructions for authors" or something similar.

It's also possible that the journal doesn't particularly care what style is used in an initial submission, and will only ask for their style to be used after the paper is accepted.  Or they may reformat it for you at that point.